# C# Struct feature - Color[(int)channel]

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

As described in the title I'm unsure what a particular feature is called when a struct is treated as an array. For example, Unity3D has the Color struct which has 4 public floats r,g,b,a and public float this[int index] { get; set; }. Is there a particular term for what this feature is called? I'm coming from Java and just starting to learn about C#, I tried to look up what this was but was only finding stuff regarding how to create an array of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called an ["indexer property"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index)

Example:

```
public struct Color
{
    public int R { get; }
    public int G { get; }
    public int B { get; }

    public int this[int index]
    {
         get
         {
             switch(index)
             {
                 case 0: return R;
                 case 1: return G;
                 case 2: return B;
             }
             throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
         }
     }
}
```

(Note: not the real `Color` you use, just an example off my head)

Comment: Thank you! Definitely was something unfamiliar to me coming from Java.

Answer (score 1):

A property like that is called **indexer**:

```
public struct Color
    private float[] components;

    public float this[int index] { //<-- indexer.
        get {
            if (components == null) {
                components = new float[4];
            }
            return components[index];
        }
        set {
            if (components == null) {
                components = new float[4];
            }
            components[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the developers of Unity3D sometimes wanted to access the [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Index_operator.html) as if it was an collection of values for ARGB (aka channels). They used the *indexer operator* in order to mimic that.

You can read more on indexer operators on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465(v=vs.71).aspx).